# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javazoom.spi.mpeg.sampled.file.MpegAudioFileReader

Tags: java, audio-streaming

I am getting this error `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javazoom.spi.mpeg.sampled.file.MpegAudioFileReader` everytime I try to instantiate a new `MpegAudioFileReader` object although my java file does compile and all the jars required (main jar and its dependencies) are included in the Build Path of the project as it is illustrated in the picture below.

[image]

Any help will be more than welcome. Thanks.